# Publish WCF Service with TFS 2015

Tags: wcf, tfs, publish

I need to publish a WCF Service inluded in a solution with a Web Site using a TFS 2015 Build.
For the Web site, i have declared a build based on a publish profile, this works perfectly with my TFS Build.

How do you configure a TFS Build to publish a WCF Service?
*Publish result means : Binary files + service.svc file + web.config*

I have tried several MsBuild configurations but i didn't manage to get the publish result i would get if i select in Visual Studio "Publish" for the WCF Service.

MSBuild Arguments => /t:Publish /p:PublishDirectory="C:\Publish\MyService"

Heres's an exemple of my configuration in TFS : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdrza.png)

MSBuild Arguments for the image => /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to publish the services to file system?

Answer (score 1):

in VSBuild task:

In sln path, give the specific solution which contains the WCF Service.

Give the following MSBuild Arguments:

```
/t:WS\(Service Assembly name) /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=TestDataProfile
```

For example if your service assembly is A.B.Service
then the ServiceAssemblyName=A_B_Service.

In PublishProfile file, you need to specify the PublishUrl with the value of file server path where we want to publish this service.

Also for access, you need to go the local machine where tfs is deploying and share the folder with TFS. You need to be an admin in order to acheive this.

After this, just queue the build and it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems you want to publish your WCF service to file system (C:\Publish\MyService). If it is, you can add [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) task in the build definition to copy the files you want to publish into a target folder, check the build definition below:

[image]